# Banner with specific colors based on picklist value

Tags: visualforce

I have an field 'Banner' in Sobject 'X'. I am trying to change the color of the  broadcast background based on the picklist value in the record. Below is the code which i tried

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" controller="Broadcast_ctrl">
<div style="border: 1px solid rgb(51, 153, 255); width: 98%; height:50px; color: black; font-size: 18px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 204);" id="NewsTicker">     
<p>
    <apex:outputPanel styleClass="{!if(BC.Priority__c == 'Low','errorClass',(if(BC.Priority__c == 'Medium','normalClass','errorClass')))}">
        <marquee><strong><b>{!message }</b></strong></marquee>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</p>
</div>
</apex:page>
<style>
.errorClass {
background-color: blue;
width: string[BC.Message__c];
}
.normalClass {
background-color: brown;
}
</style>
```

Comment: What is the issue with above code ?

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: @PrabhatKumar i'm passing banner values from latest 5 records and color which  results in is only satisfying latest record. For Example record1 has priority as low and record2 has priority as medium. Here the color for banner of record1 should be blue and for banner of record2 should be brown but the result is brown. Note: I'm showing all Banners in single page.

Comment: @Himanshu i'm passing banner values from latest 5 records and color which results in is only satisfying latest record. For Example record1 has priority as low and record2 has priority as medium. Here the color for banner of record1 should be blue and for banner of record2 should be brown but the result is brown. Note: I'm showing all Banners in single page.

Comment: Are you using apex repeat to display the data ?

Comment: @PrabhatKumar Sorry, I'm new to SFDC can you be bit specific about where to use apex repeat tag.